# Android sqlite leaving connection open

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I create a SQLiteDatabase instance and call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()` and manipulate data that way but I never close the database via `db.close()`. Is it bad to not close it? I tried adding `db.close()` to my `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` methods but it just force closes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a connection as late as possible.  Close it as soon as possible. Close it in a "finally" block to make sure it gets closed.

And in general, dispose of resources in the reverse order that you obtain them.

Comment: I've got a logger program and I'm wondering if it really makes sense to open and close the database so often (e.g. every second when logging GPS).  Also, the variant I am using (sqlcipher) seems to crash in the open every several thousand opens and only opening it once per app start would be a workaround. (This is in a Service, btw)

Answer (score 2):

You are basically bloating your application by having an extra cursor open. Best practice is to close the connection.

I have noticed that there are a lot of exceptions thrown if you dont do it.

Comment: Where would it be appropriate to close the database?

Comment: @semajhan I usually close it at OnPause() method of Activity

Answer (score 0):

If you don't close the database connections, they'll cause memory leaks over time. you can use startManagingCursor but along with this you have to close the db connection. by the way what type of error or exception you are getting while closing db connection in onStop() or onDestroy() method