# Closing an SQLite database on one thread breaks the database opened on another thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

We all [learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637309/android-sqlite-leaving-connection-open) that resources, such as database connections, should be acquired late and released early.

Yet applying this principle to SQLite database connections on Android have caused me some headache.

I have an app that download updates from a backend server in a service working in the background, writing updates to the database at a regular basis. The problem I experience arise when the following sequence occurs:

1. Service opens a writable database connection
2. Some activity opens a readable database connection
3. Service closes its database connection **concurrently** with the activity reading data
4. Activity fails due to its database connection was closed

Both the service and the activity uses the same [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) class, though different instances, to open their connections. My initial assumption was that this should work just fine, but somehow it seems that the underlying connection is shared between the two database instances.

To work around the problem I ended up **not closing** the database objects, only closing any opened cursors. This seems to work, though I'm not sure that I'm not leaking memory here.

Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by "concurrently"? Is the service running a background thread?

Comment: @Graham: yes, as mentioned, the service is working is doing its work in the background on a separate thread.

Comment: and yes, by concurrently I mean "at the same time".

Comment: Are you instantiating two subclasses of SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: @Tim: yes, as mentioned, instances of the helper class are not shared.

Comment: @Peter: is there a functional difference in Android between an instance of a class and an instance of a subclass of that class?

Comment: @Tim: sorry, am a bit confused with your query. No, there's no functional difference, they will all be different instances. My point was, I'm not accidentally using the *same* instance of my helper class, which could've explained the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something obvious I am missing here?

I'd say no. Looking at the source code to `SQLiteOpenHelper`, I can't see how two instances could be sharing a `SQLiteDatabase` object.

Some diagnostic suggestions:

- Dump the `toString()` value of each `SQLiteDatabase`, which should give you a Java instance ID. If they are the same, that is where your problem lies, and you will need to work your way upstream to figure out how the heck this is happening (e.g., you really are using the same instance of the `SQLiteOpenHelper`).
- With your database in a stable state (i.e., no need to create or upgrade), flip one of your two database spots to use `SQLiteDatabase` directly, rather than via `SQLiteOpenHelper`, and see if that changes matters.

Comment: thanks for the input. Since I'm using roboguice to inject instances, I have done tests that asserts that roboguice actually are serving up unique instances per dependency. I will try to do a more isolated test with `SQLiteOpenHelper` and `SQLiteDatabase` as you suggest.